# Rails & Heroku: bash: rails: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to get into my rails heroku database. Usually I just run:

```
heroku run rails console
```

but it's giving me an error: `bash: rails: command not found`

I have no idea what caused this. Haven't updated my project code.

```
heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.36.5 (x86_64-darwin15) ruby/2.2.4
heroku-cli/5.6.14-b0cc983 (darwin-amd64) go1.7.4
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-redis@1.2.8
```

Comment: Might sound stupid but are you in the correct working directory and did you add the remote to heroku correctly to an rails app?

Comment: Haha I think it probably will be something stupid... But double checked and all looks good (projectname git:(master) git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git)

Comment: Also works locally

Comment: @NickM rbenv but not really sure what next steps would be to debug

Comment: so it works locally, how would I fix on heroku? I can run rails c locally.

Answer (score 4):

The same happened to me. My problem was that I didn't commit my changes before the first push, so I didn't have the project up. I did:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin heroku
```

then, before trying rails c, you need to setup the database.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I followed this [devcenter.heroku: getting started with rails4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#local-workstation-setup)